# Basic If/Else statement question

Tags: ruby, syntax, if-statement

I'm getting a strange error: "syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND" and it points to the final line of my code.

New to Ruby and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

```
 def add(x,y)
      if(x > y)
        c = x + y
        return c

  else
    puts "Y is too big"
    return   
end


a = 4
b = 6

add(a,b)
```

Comment: If you're adding, why does it matter that x is greater than y?

Comment: I'm just playing with basic if statements. Not thinking too intensely about the logic here. Working on fundamentals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corrected code (you are missing one end for the if-else):

```
def add(x,y)
    if(x > y)
        c = x + y
        return c
    else
        puts "Y is too big"
        return   
    end
end

a = 4
b = 6

add(a,b)
```

Answer (score 6):

BTW, you can refactor your if..end statement out completely if you prefer

```
def add(x,y)
  return (x + y) if(x > y)
  puts "Y is too big"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Both [`if`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/) statements and [function definitions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-function-method-syntax/) require an `end` statement to terminate them.

Try adding another `end` after your existing `end` and your problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

wap to input principle, rate, time and choice. if choice is 1 than calculate simple interest, if choice is 2 calculate compund interest and if it is other than 1 or 2 print "Enter valid choice"

Comment: Hi David, welcome! It's great you chime in, sadly in this instance you add an answer, where there are already better answers. Try to read the question carefully, as his problems is actually missing and end clause and you answer is just restating his problem statement. But keep contributig please, don't take possible downvotes as discouragment, but as encouragement to improve your answers ;-)